# "TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" in on_message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

**Info:**
I was working on my bot recently, and was able to make the bot react on message if you have  a command in the channel's topic (Description). I've looked up and tried everything I could, but none worked. The bot's console gets spammed with errors, though the reactions work. I did noticed though that since I implemented this, my bot only works in some servers and completely stopped (Besides the on_message reactions) in other servers. I have no clue why it works in some over others and haven't been able to figure that out either.

**Error:**

```
  File "FILENAME", line NUMBER, in on_message
    if "S|Wave" in message.channel.topic:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

**Code:**

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "S|Wave" in message.channel.topic:
        await message.add_reaction("")
```

If it helps, I have multiple of these under on_message, including ping reactions and other on_message events.

Comment: `message.channel.topic` is None.  We can't say why that is, because you haven't shown us the full code.

Comment: Do you expect that the topic could be some sort of collection? You are asking if `"S|wave"` is `in` a collection of objects, and it seems that `message.channel.topic` is not a collection but is set to None for some reason.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20channel#discord.Message.channel), `message.channel` can be a `TextChannel`, `VoiceChannel`, `Thread`, `DMChannel`, `GroupChannel` or `PartialMessageable` object (I guess depending on some kind of context? I don't use discord, and have never used this API). Some of those types have a `topic` member, some do not.

Comment: In fact, `TextChannel` seems to be the only one of these types that has a `topic` attribute, so that attribute will be `None` for all the others. If `topic` is `None`, iteration will fail when attempting to use the `in` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `on_message` and since it does have a topic this suggests that the channel can only be a `TextChannel`.

This doesn't really matter but the channel that you're sending a message in doesn't have a set topic and so it will return `None`. You could solve this by adding a quick if statement eg.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "S|Wave" in message.channel.topic if message.channel.topic else "":
        await message.add_reaction("")
```